# Need some help to submit a value in the database - phpBB

Tags: php, html, phpbb

Well guys, to ask the question is pretty simple, but myself, I'm having a problem on finding the answer, and I need this badly...

The question is:

I have the following function in (donate/index.php)

function submitted_amount()
{
    global $db, $user, $auth, $template, $current_dir;
    global $config, $phpbb_root_path, $phpbb_admin_path, $phpEx;

```
    include ($phpbb_root_path . 'includes/functions_user.' . $phpEx);
    include ($phpbb_root_path . 'includes/functions_posting.' . $phpEx);
    include_once ($phpbb_root_path . 'donate/functions_donate.' . $phpEx);

    $submitted_amount = (isset($_POST['submitted_amount'])) ? true : false;

    $sql = 'UPDATE ' . DONATION_TABLE . "
            SET config_value = '" . $submitted_amount . "'
            WHERE config_name = 'submitted_amount'";

    $result = $db->sql_query($sql);
```

}

page_header($user->lang['DONATE_EXPLAIN'], false);

submitted_amount();

$template->set_filenames(array(
    'body' => 'donate/index_body.html')
);

?>

Now the file: (styles/prosilver/template/donate/index_body.html)

It has the following line

< input type='text' name='submitted_amount' id='submitted_amount' value='' size="25" tabindex="1" maxlength='9' class='inputbox_d' align="top">

< form action='{U_DONATE_CONFIRM}' method='post'>

< input type='submit' class="button1" name='submit' value='{L_SUBMIT}'>

If you need more clarifications please tell me. I showed you all possible connections between the HTML and the PHP of my code. The database column is there, so what's my problem?

Comment: What is your question? What doesn't work? What does debugging output tell you - are the form values not submitted, or is it a problem at insertion...?

Comment: I cannot send the value from the input type="text" into the database.

Comment: Is the 'submitted_amount' input element inside the form element? If it isn't, it won't be submitted. Try using something like Firebug to see what exactly is being sent in the POST request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first off:

```
$submitted_amount = (isset($_POST['submitted_amount'])) ? true : false;
```

shouldn't this be the value of `submitted_amount`? it will only ever be `true` or `false`.

quick fix would be to change `true` to `$_POST['submitted_amount']`, however you'll be leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection unless you add some variable checking somewhere in there.

Comment: Well, phpBB uses request_var('value_to_send', '');. But my problem is I cannot store the value from my template to the database.

With some easy steps to explain, this is what I want to do:
1. in the text field the user enters a value
2. The user hits "Submit" to submit the value in the text field
3. That value gets stored/saved in the database, in the table and column of my choice.

Comment: what's happening with the current code? giving an error? not getting the right value in your database?